Why I am getting wrong mA on Tinkercad?
I am trying out TinkerCAD and I am using an Arduino.
When I light up my led it says, "Current trough led is 26.1 mA while recommended is 20 mA."
But according to Ohm's law it should be higher than 26.1 mA?
What I have connected.

5V from Arduino
110 ohm resistor

5/110 = roughly 0,045 = 45 mA.

Why is TinkerCAD saying that my LED is having 26.1 mA running trough it? Or is it something I'm missing?

You need to subtract away the LED voltage from 5 V, first. Plus, and i don't know if tinker handles this, but the I/O pins also have some source resistance that does not show on the schematic but does affect the current.

Ok so my LED have some built-in resistor?

The LED has a non-linear equation - doesn't look anything like a resistor. Well, actually, a non-linear equation part plus a resistor part, to be more honest. But the LED can be considered to be like a "zener" in a sense, where it has a fixed voltage drop across it no matter what the current is. Except that it does vary a little bit with current. So to keep things simple you can look at the datasheet and see what voltage they specify as typical and just use that, subtracting it from the voltage supply before dividing by your added current limit resistor. You get get in the weeds if you want.

@periblepsis From the schematic the Arduino I/O pins don't seem to involved in controlling the LED. R2 and D1 appear to be directly connected across the 5 V supply.

@ChesterGillon Yeah. True. I didn't look at the schematic close enough. But if the I/O pins get used.... Thanks for the clarity!

the arduino is irrelevant to the LED circuit ... it is not part of the LED circuit

The voltage over resistor is not 5V, so no the current should not be 45mA.
According to your simulator there is 2.871V drop over resistor.
The remaining 2.129V are dropped over the LED.
And no, LEDs do not obey Ohm's law as they are not resistors, they are diodes.
LEDs also don't generally have built-in resistors, but these do exist.

Where is there a 2.871V drop?

@Bojje I said over the resistor. You have 110 ohm resistor and 26.1mA current runs through it. Use Ohm's law to find voltage over resistor.

Ah ok so when voltage goes trough the resistors it drops the voltage? Is there a formula for how much Ohm drops voltage?

@Bojje No, when current goes through resistor it drops voltage. The formula you already used in your question is called Ohm's Law. You just assumed all 5V is over resistor, but all 5V is over both the resistor and LED, so there will not be 5V over the resistor.

Trying to grasp what you mean but I don't get with what you say with
" but all 5V is over both the resistor and LED, so there will not be 5V over the resistor."
The voltage goes trough the resistor first? Then it is 5V ?

@Bojje I have said many times it isn't 5V on both ends of resistor. Voltage does not go through. Voltage drops in a resistor when current flows.  Ohm's law, you calculated all 5V drops in a resistor, so there is 0V over LED, and LEDs do not work if there are 0V over them, there is no current.

Ok so it first travel trough resistor with gives lower volt/current and then trough the led wich also "causes" lower mA? cause it is a diode?

@Bojje Not because it is a diode. You can think it is an unknown load, a mystery component. All you know when you connect is that you have 26.1mA flowing into it and 2.129V over it. Which means, it could be a LED or anything equivalent like a 81.57 ohm resistor. I don't understand what you are confused about. Resistors and LEDs are basic stuff. Your circuit has a LED that passes 26.1mA with 2.129V over it. And your 110 ohm resistor has 26.1mA through it and 2.871V over it. The circuit voltage sums up to 5V which you have.

Using the built-in Circuit LAB simulator and showing the current through the LED and voltage across the LED might be helpful to visualise what is happening:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Used the default Circuit LAB LED LTL-307EE part number, which is a red LED. The datasheet has the following curve which shows how the LED forward current varies with forward voltage:

Curcuit LAB has the ability to change the SPICE model which is used to model the non-linear forward voltage varies with forward voltage current:

I haven't used Tinkercad to know if that tool also provides a similar capability to change the model used for a LED.
